# FCM push notification not showing when the app is opened, got message, but just playing sound

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app just playing sound when the apps is opened (not in background).
App received the message but not showing in the notification.

When i close the application or just let app in the background, notification appear.

can you help me why this happen ?

i wanna show notification message even when the app is opened
please help me..

**Here is my notificationutil.java**

```
private Context mContext;
    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message,
                                        final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;

        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_bpnicon_48;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);

        final Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

                Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message,
                            timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                } else {
                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp,
                            resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
                }
            }
        } else {
            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }

    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon,
                                       String title, String message, String timeStamp,
                                       PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        Log.e(TAG, "showSmallNotification: "+"Small" );
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder,
                                     int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp,
                                     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        Log.e(TAG, "showBigNotification: "+ "Big" );
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);


        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

// Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        Log.e(TAG, "playNotificationSound: "+"show" );
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "isAppIsInBackground: "+"show" );
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND &&
                        processInfo.processName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "clearNotifications: "+"show" );
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }
```

**And this is my firebase service, 
MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
        Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

            String title = data.getString("title");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
            String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
            String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
            JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
            Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
            Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
            Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

                // check for image attachment
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message,
                            timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text only
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message,
                                         String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "showNotificationMessage: "+"show");
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Showing notification with text and image
     */
    private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message,
                                                     String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
        Log.e(TAG, "showNotificationMessageWithBigImage: "+"show" );
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
    }
```

**This is method resume in the LoginActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREFS_LOGGED, false);

        if (loggin) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem

**Changing this code :**

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
```

**With this :**

```
private void handleNotification(String message) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
//            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            Intent intent = new Intent( this , MainActivity.class );
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_bpnicon_48)
                    .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel( true )
                    .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                    .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());

        }else{
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
            Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "handleNotification: "+"background" );
        }
    }
```